# Implementing Notification System

Tags: android, .net, ios, sql-server

Basically what I'm trying to do is a system that each time there is a new user added to a SQL Server database, it sends a notification to the android and iOS app I'm developing. I was planning to use the Google Cloud Messaging, but the notifications need to get to the iOS application as well. What do you suggest me to implement? I was thinking of using GCM for the android app and APN for the iOs app, but is there a simplier unified way to implement a system like this?

Comment: GCM and APNS is the only best way to implement, according to me. And its really easy to implement both.

Comment: They're really simple to implement, but I was trying to see if there was an alternative way (like a web service) that directly interacts with the phone regardless the operating system. Anyways, implementing APN and GCM seems like the best option.

Comment: If you go with Webservice, then Server cannot respond unless client sends any request. So in that case ur app has to poll server 24X7 every minute to check if any change has occurred at server side which would cost a lot of unnecessary packet data. And thats why GCM and APNS are the best choice here where server will tell clients when any change occurs on server side.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself yet, but I have this bookmarked for future exploration.  It seems easy and does all of what you want.  https://pushover.net/

But as far as my experience, GCM is great and pretty easy to implement on Android.  No iOS development experience here.

Comment: It is a good option, neverless it requires that the user installs the pushover app. I forgot to mention it that the message should be displayed on the app I'm developing for android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a trigger to send out an email everytime you have added a user